# How to calculate pitch angle between two 3d vectors

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I'm making an AI in my spacesim game and trying to get pitch and yaw between enemy's direction vector and direction to some target. Here is the method to move towards the target:

```
private void moveTo(Vecf target) {
    if (target == null)
        return;
    Vecf dir = getForward();
    Vecf dirToTarget = Vecf.sub(target, pos).normalize();
    float dYaw = getYaw(dir, dirToTarget);
    float dPitch = getPitch(dir, dirToTarget);
    rotate(dPitch, dYaw);
    moveForward();
}
```

I've already written the `getYaw(Vecf v1, Vecf v2)` method but I have no idea what to do with the pitch. Can someone help me with this? Btw angles are in radians.

Answer (score -1):

you need both forward and up vectors to compute pitch and yaw

Comment: The AI class has both forward and up vectors but what should I do with them